# Changing name of figures and tables in Executive summary

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, floats, captions

I wrote an executive summary for my thesis, but the figures and tables that I include in this executive summary are numbered as follows: 0.1, 0.2, etc.

I was wondering whether or not this is officially accepted and if it is not, whether there is a way to change the numbering. I like that the numbering in the rest of the chapters show the chapter number, but the zero in the executive summary looks a little bit strange. Thank you for the help! I leave you my code here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\leftmargin$#1$}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lscape}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}p{0.1\textwidth}}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{M}{p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\usepackage{longtable,array,ragged2e}
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-1.5\tabcolsep-0.25\arrayrulewidth\relax}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\RaggedRight}p{\mylen}}


\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}


\begin{document}
\section*{Management Summary}
The supplier selection problem is one of the crucial activities of the procuring department in an organization when no single supplier can satisfy all....

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=.43]{Model blackbox.png}}
\begin{changemargin}{0.5cm}{0.5cm}
\vspace*{-2mm}
\caption{Can Order Allocation Model (COAM) framework.}
\end{changemargin}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}


To test the financial benefits, five different versions of the model were built....

\end{document}
```

Comment: The optional argument of \caption provides a "short caption" for use in the list of figures/tables.  You can change the numbering (at creation) using `\renewcommand{\thetable}{...}`.

Answer (score 1):

I have added to your MWE but didn't waste time removing all the irrevelant code that you gave that had no relationship to your problem.

```
% fignumprob.tex  SE 561990

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\captionsetup[table]{font=small,labelfont=bf}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\leftmargin$#1$}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{lscape}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}p{0.1\textwidth}}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{M}{p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\usepackage{longtable,array,ragged2e}
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-1.5\tabcolsep-0.25\arrayrulewidth\relax}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\RaggedRight}p{\mylen}}


\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rom}[1]{\expandafter\@slowromancap\romannumeral #1@}
\makeatother
\def\changemargin#1#2{\list{}{\rightmargin#2\leftmargin#1}\item[]}
\let\endchangemargin=\endlist 

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}}


\begin{document}
\listoffigures %%  PW ADDED THIS
\section*{Management Summary}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}} %% PW ADDED THIS
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}} %% PW ADDED THIS

The supplier selection problem is one of the crucial activities of the procuring department in an organization when no single supplier can satisfy all....

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centerline{\includegraphics[scale=.43]{Model blackbox.png}}
\begin{changemargin}{0.5cm}{0.5cm}
\vspace*{-2mm}
\caption{Can Order Allocation Model (COAM) framework.}
\end{changemargin}
\label{fig}
\end{figure}


To test the financial benefits, five different versions of the model were built....

\section{Main document}  %% PW ADDED THESE

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection.\arabic{table}}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
MAIN ILLUSTRATION
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Use `\renewcommand{figure}` (and table) at appropriate places to get the numbering you want. I don't know how you want your List of Figures to look but it seems odd to me that the Management Summary one is labelled `1` but the Main Document one is labelled `1.1`. If you don't like this ask another question.

The `article` class does not provide chapters which you talk about in your question. --- GOM